# how get time where ocurres a word in STT on android?

Tags: android

I look on android API for STT but I cannot see where could I get a time when the recognised word was spoken. 
In my app I want to record spoken sentence and then some how link text and recorded voice. If Android API could return not only word but also time e.g. in milliseconds form beginning).

How can I do it?